# Flash banner advert with html link

Tags: html, flash, hyperlink, clicktag

I'm working on a website which has advert banners which link to external pages.

I've recently added the ability to have flash banners, but am stuck on how to make the banners link without editing the flash file.

The idea is that clients wanting to advertise on the site send a flash advert which is then linked to their site through the CMS, however unless the client embeds the link into the flash file, or add a flashvar parameter which can then pull in the info from the database, the flash banner doesn't link as it's seems not to link being surrounded by an <a> tag.

This is probably a well known thing, but this is my first time doing flash adverts, so I'm coming to it from a completely novice position.

What's the best solution? Is this something than anyone creating a flash advert would know about and instinctively do or will it need to be instructed to the client before hand, or is there a way to get it to be a link through html?

Cheer

Comment: what would you suggest is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a clicktag. It's a script inside the flashfile that looks for an address as a GET parameter to the flash file and adds a link to this address. See [here](http://www.flashclicktag.com/) for a tutorial on how to implement a clicktag in flash.

This is something anyone who makes flash adverts is used to.

Comment: thanks for the response, hope this is the case with the clients we work with.