# Add a Link Around an Embedded Flash File

Tags: html, css, flash, clicktag

I want to make it so that when I click anywhere on the embedded Flash element, it takes me to a destination URL.

Here is my current code, which does not produce the desired effect:

```
<div class="contentdiv" style="margin:-72px 0 10px 0px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="location.href='http://example.com/';">

<object height="410" width="720">
<param name="movie" value="images/tri.swf">
<embed src="images/tri.swf" height="400" width="700"> 
</embed>
</object>

</div>
```

Right now it is making the space behind the .swf file clickable for the link, but the Flash element is not clickable.

If the right thing to do is to edit the .swf file somehow, please let me know that. I don't consider myself a Flash developer, but are there any resources on where to get started or how to do something this basic with an existing .swf file?

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update after more research:**

This question has been asked before, and the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660996/flash-banner-advert-with-html-link/1661028#1661028) is that you have to create the link within flash.

Usually this is done dynamically by passing a parameter (conventionally named clickTAG) to the .swf to tell it where to link to.

In your case (since someone else provided your swf files) I can see 2 options:

1. Your .swf author may have already implemented the [clickTAG method](http://www.flashclicktag.com/) (you can ask them, or just try it out on the .swf to see if it works.)
2. You could make a flash wrapper file that implements clickTag, and have it load and display your .swf file. I know this seems like a hack, but I can't see any other alternatives.

Hope this helps!

---

I've also seen something like this used [edit: but I can't get it to work! Googling suggests that it's not possible]

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">
 <object height="410" width="720"><param name="movie" value="images/tri.swf">
 <embed src="images/tri.swf" height="400" width="700"></embed>
 </object>
</a>
```

(For example [here](http://www.flashadvisor.com/forum/dynamic-variable-names-t1595.html))

Comment: I tried implementing this and it did not work. Also, your link goes to a forum page that appears un-related to this topic.

Comment: The link is to a page with a flash banner ad: look at the page source to see how they did it!

Comment: Ok, I looked at the source code, and it's a little unclear because of the way they're setting up that example. They have the <a> tag going around the flash element and the text that comes after it. It's not clear if that <a> tag enables the linking for the flash element or not. For example, it could be because of the <a> tag or it could be because of the way the flash swf file is constructed.

In any case, as I explained in my first comment, I tried implementing this with a simple <a> tag as you described, but it did not work. I don't think this is the appropriate fix.

Comment: You're right - I can't make it work either! Maybe there's a reason neither method works, like one of the parameters used to embed the swf? I'll do some more digging...

Comment: Thank you, this helps me get where we need to go.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem, found this thread, but ended up creating my own solution.

I added transparent element to the link, then made it overlap the embeded swf

```
<a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">
  <object height="410" width="720"><param name="movie" value="http://www.theslap.com/swf/slap_logo.swf">
    <embed src="http://www.theslap.com/swf/slap_logo.swf" height="400" width="700"></embed>
  </object>
  <i style="display:block; height: 410px; width: 720px;  position: relative; z-index: 9; margin-top: -410px;"></i>
</a>
```

Note - you should probably include the css in a separate file for production code.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did except I used a `div` instead of an `i` tag, and I used `top` instead of `margin-top` in the style tag.  Seems to do just what I need it to do.  Thanks again.

Comment: I also had to change the Flash mode from window to opaque by adding this inside the object tag `<param name="wmode" value="opaque">` and this attribute of the embed tag `wmode="opaque"`.

Answer (score 3):

Put a transparent .gif or .png file over the flash using z-index and just anchor that transparent image with your URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own swf (or have someone do it for you) that has a button editable with [`FlashVars`](http://blog.six4rty.ch/tutorials/flash-flashvars-in-as3/) over the stage and that loads in your subject swf underneath that button.

I've created one for you: [Download](http://projectavian.com/filesLoader.zip).

You just need to add two FlashVars when you embed it:

1. `url` - The URL that will be visited if the swf is clicked.
2. `swf` - The swf file to load.

Answer (score 1):

I got mad to solve the issue....  I tried several tricks including jquery and javascript.

Definitely the SOLUTION that works and works in ALL browser is the one above my reply.

Thanks user user2628529

```
            <div class="containe">
              <div  style="position:absolute;"> <a href="http://www.sample.com" target="_blank" > <img src="http://www.sample.it/banner/trasparent-190-505.png"> </a> </div>
              <div >
                <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://www.sample.it/banner/banner-one.swf' width='190' height='505'>
                  <param name='flashvars' value='clickTag=&clickTarget=_self' />
                  <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always' />
                  <param name='movie' value='banner-one.swf' />
                  <param name='wmode' value='transparent' >
                </object>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you do not need the png.  a simple empty div (with same dimension) also works for me.  but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There is a best way i've got found

```
<div class="flash-wrap">
   <a class="flash-link" href="#"></a>
   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flash.swf" width="180" height="220">
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
      <param name="movie" value="flash.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
   </object>
</div>
```

```
 .flash-wrap{
         position: relative;
         }

      .flash-link{
         position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
         width:180px; /*Flash Size*/
         height:220px; 
         /*background: url('images/0.gif') no-repeat;*/ /*You should uncommented this line for support old IE version.*/
         }
```

https://gist.github.com/m-pokrovskii/6558817

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="logo" >
   <div id="linklogo" style="position:absolute;"><a href="http://www.gogle.com"><img src="transparent.png"></a></div>
   <div id="flashlogo" >
    <object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='1.swf' width='200' height='86'>     <param name='flashvars' value='clickTag=&clickTarget=_self' /><param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always' /><param name='movie' value='1.swf' /><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></object>
</div>
```

certainly
eliminates the problem in all cases

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{ entity.link }}">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{{ entity.file.path }}?clickTAG={{ entity.link }}" width="120" height="600" style="visibility: visible;">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
        <param name="play" value="true">
        <param name="LOOP" value="false">
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="true">
    </object>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You! 
now. It worked

```
    <div style="width: 400px; height: 100px;">
    <a href="http://www.sample.com" target="_blank">
    <object height="100" width="400"><param name="movie" value="1.swf">
      <embed src="1.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="400" height="100" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" allowScriptAccess="always"></embed>
    </object>  
      <i style="display: block; height: 100px; width: 400px; position: relative;z-index: 9;margin-top: -102px;"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a link to a flash object, but **you can overlap a transparent image with a link**, over the flash object.
This is my example:

```
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: absolute;
        left: 250px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 9999;">
            <a href="http://terrazasmedicina.com.ar/hometerrazas.html">
<img src="logoLinkTR.png" width="504" height="103"></a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,28,0','width','1024','height','106','src','banner','quality','high','pluginspage','http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash','movie','banner' ); //end AC code
    </script></div>
```

In my case the object is embeded by a script, but it should work the same.
You have to **wrap in a relative div the object and a div with the image**, and then position as **absolute** the div with the image aligning it by **left, top, right and bottom properties**, and asigning **z-index** property to overlap the image.